# Stable Configuration for DNN 5.6

Tags: dotnetnuke

What is the recommended configuration for installing DNN 5.6 like the web server, SQL Server etc?

Comment: @Jeff - How about an edit "What is the minimum windows server configuration for DNN 5.6.2?"

Answer (score 1):

**Windows Server 2008 R2**

- It is probably best to fire up an Amazon EC2 Micro or Small instance with a Windows 2008 R2 AMI

  - Note, if you want to run it on a micro (it will be a little bit sluggish)

    - If you do, I suggest installing on a Large, but then right clicking the instance and converting it back to a microafter installation
  - **I prefer to install on a Medium 32-bit instance, and then back them down to a Small 32-bit instance after installation**

    - I think a reserved 3-year Small Instance on US-East is one of the best investments in the tech world right now.

**Sql Server 2008 R2 Express**

- Once you have your Windows Server 2008 R2 server running, download and install Sql Express
- I prefer to install SQL Express myself, because I can install Sql 2008 R2 Express -- last time I checked, only SQL 2008 Express (not R2) were available in AMI's

**Pre-DNN Security**

- Create a "www" folder on your data drive (With Amazon EC2, It's OK to use your operating system drive. Just remember to take snapshots early and often).
- Change the permissions on that folder so that "users" no longer have access.
- Add Read/Write access for Network Service / IUsr
- Open up Port 80 (IP Restrict it if you want to keep the site private initially)

**Post-DNN Security**

- IP-restrict access to the bin folder
- Verify that you have a dedicated SQL user for the DNN Database (Don't use the SA account).
- Make sure you have updated the Admin and Host accounts to have secure passwords
- Make sure the OS has automatic updates on

**Post-DNN Performance**

- You will want some sort of Pinger / Page-hitter application running that accesses various pages on your site. This will help keep the Application Pool fresh and keep the appropriate Modules and Pages nicely cached.

  - This is critical for a speedy DNN experience. DNN is lightning quick, as long as all its parts are in memory and properly cached.
- I recommend setting the App Pool to recycle every night at 4:00 AM Central
- I also recommend setting the timeout / idle time of the App Pool to be 24 hours

**Play with the Amazon .NET SDK**

- The Amazon SDK is pretty nifty -- I suggest writing an application that is designed to do the following

  - Should be called daily via a windows task
  - Examines a config file for combinations of AWS Access Keys, Secret Keys, and Volume IDs
  - Creates a snapshot of each volume based upon some defined schedule
  - Deletes old snapshots that are no longer needed
- Using this method, I usually keep 5 daily shapshots, 4 weekly snapshots, and 6 monthly snapshots -- all of which are automatically managed by this nice utility.

**Misc Discussion**

- A Micro will run DNN OK (even with SQL Express running). You will get some hiccups (~3-second page loads due to the OS dealing with Virtual Memory) You would want to limit the memory usage of SQL Express, shut down non-essential services, and make sure you only install the necessary DNN modules.

  - Most Importantly, you will want a "Pinger" application to fairly-often access various pages on your site. This is not only to keep the App Pool fresh, but it will also keep important bits of data firmly planted in memory. The Micro's have so little memory that this is extra important.
- If you need to run this outside the cloud, I can recommend a low-end dedicated server at 1&1, although I shut down my last 1&1 server and am exclusively on EC2 now.
- If you prefer something on-location, you can also run on a cheap SSD & 2 Ghz Single-core processor with at least 1.5 GB of memory (provided you have Windows 2008 R2 running, I can't speak for 2003). Don't forget to keep current backups! The SSD isn't required, but it is dollar-for-dollar the best investment you can make in almost any computer purchase or upgrade -- and it's so far ahead of the pack it's a no-brainer.